# Vertical Layout not showing widgets

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to create a vertical layout with pyqt according to the code detailed below. The problem is that, once I execute it, the window does not contain any button at all...
I have tried with different first layout examples and none of them work properly.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Thank you very much

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.createLayout()

    def createLayout(self):

        b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button1")
        b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button2")
        b3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button3")
        b4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button4")

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(b1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(b2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(b3)
        mainLayout.addWidget(b4)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Form Layout")
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    windowForm = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: 1. remove `self.setLayout(mainLayout)`

Comment: 2. add `central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)`